# android how do you dynamically change a radiogroup based on the radiogroups selection

Tags: android

I get an error on the "button2.setOnClickListener(**radio_listener**);"

Because its embedded inside the onclick listener calling itself, whats the way around this?

```
    final RadioGroup rGroup3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_gcam);

    OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton button = (RadioButton) v;
            no_of_gcams = 3;
            gcam_names_array[0] = "Machine 1";
            gcam_names_array[1] = "Machine 2";
            gcam_names_array[2] = "Machine 3";
            gcam_names_array[3] = "Machine 4";

            for (int i = 0; i < no_of_gcams; i++)
            {

            RadioButton button2 = new RadioButton(ModbusDroid.this);
            button2.setText(gcam_names_array[i]);
            button2.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);      
            rGroup3.addView(button2);

            }
        }
    };

    if (no_of_gcams == 0)
    {
    RadioButton button1 = new RadioButton(this);
    button1.setText("Setup a G-CAM");

    button1.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
    rGroup3.addView(button1);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below snippet and it will help:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Cheers, simple but effective :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Now i have the problem ive moved the "button2.setOnClickListener(this);" somewhere else and the this cannot be initialised, any ideas.?  Might do away with the check boxes making a new check boxes and put a button in the menu to create mote options. Chris

```
final OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton button = (RadioButton) v;
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),button.getText(), 5).show();

            no_of_gcams = no_of_gcams+1;


            LayoutInflater factory2 = LayoutInflater.from(ModbusDroid.this);
            textEntryNumericView = factory2.inflate(R.layout.write_value_numeric, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder writeNumericDialogBuilder = new
                AlertDialog.Builder(ModbusDroid.this);
            writeNumericDialogBuilder.setTitle("Write to Register")
                .setView(textEntryNumericView)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_edit)
                .setMessage("Value to Write to Register")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", 
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Write", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                gcam_names_array[0] = ((EditText) textEntryNumericView.findViewById(R.id.write_value_number)).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Writing Value: " + gcam_names_array[0], 5).show();

                RadioButton button2 = new RadioButton(ModbusDroid.this);
                button2.setText(gcam_names_array[0]);
                button2.setId(no_of_gcams);
                button2.setOnClickListener(this);      
                rGroup3.addView(button2);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

            writeNumericRegisterDialog = writeNumericDialogBuilder.create();
            writeNumericRegisterDialog = writeNumericDialogBuilder.show();

        }
      };
```